# KafkaStream reaches ERROR state on rolling upgrade of brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Kafka 2.8.1 (AWS MSK). I am observing whenever some rolling upgrade is done by AWS my Kafka stream application reaches an ERROR state and I keep getting the below exceptions on trying to query the state store

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when retrieving state store.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.InteractiveQueryService.lambda$getHostInfo$3(InteractiveQueryService.java:237)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.**InteractiveQueryService.getHostInfo(InteractiveQueryService.java:222)**
    at com.sp.gos.processors.GossiperKVStoreQueryService.getHostInfo(GossiperKVStoreQueryService.java:108)
    at com.sp.gos.processors.GossiperKVStoreQueryService.get(GossiperKVStoreQueryService.java:68)
...
caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.validateIsRunningOrRebalancing(KafkaStreams.java:381)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.queryMetadataForKey(KafkaStreams.java:1663)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.InteractiveQueryService.lambda$getHostInfo$2(InteractiveQueryService.java:227)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.tryAdvance(HashMap.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.InteractiveQueryService.lambda$getHostInfo$3(InteractiveQueryService.java:228)
```

I also have a Log and continue exception handler added in properties like below and I do not see the code reaching there whenever I run into this issue

```
props.put(
        "default.deserialization.exception.handler",
        LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
props.put(
        "default.production.exception.handler",
        LogAndContinueProductionExceptionHandler.class);
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong? Is there any misconfiguration on my part which is causing this issue? What is the recommended way to deal with this type of issues? Once I restart my application, everything starts working fine.

- `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar` - 3.0.9
- `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` - 3.5.1
- `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` - 4.0.4
- `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams` - 3.5.1